# How to change my object from being only one object with arrays inside, to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

So I've got this part of a code where I'm creating response for my project. Now I've managed to create data, but I've got response that I need to changes.

First here is my code:

```
exports.getById = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.a_id;

  articleService
    .getById(id)
    .then((article) => {
      bankService
        .getRates()
        .then((list) => {
          let prr = article.price;
          let price = parseFloat(prr.replace(/\.| ?€$/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
          let mjeseci = req.body.months;

          let ratanks = list.map((rata) =>
            LoanJS.Loan(price, !mjeseci ? 60 : mjeseci, rata.NKS)
          );

          const kreditNKS = ratanks.map((index) => index.sum);
          const rataNKS = ratanks.map(
            (index) => index.installments[0].installment
          );

          let eks = list.map((stopa) => stopa.EKS);
          let name = list.map((ime) => ime.bank.name);
          let nks = list.map((stopa) => stopa.NKS);
          let type = list.map((ime) => ime.interest_type.name);

          res.status(200).json({
            kredit: {
              kreditNKS: kreditNKS,
              rataNKS: rataNKS,
              stopaEKS: eks,
              stopaNKS: nks,
              tip: type,
              ime: name,
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).send('Error 1 ->' + err);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send('Error ->' + err);
    });
};
```

Explain of what it does: So I'm fetching single article from my DB which has price inside it, then I'm getting data about loan also from DB. Now I'm using that data from DB, using `.map` function to get values one by one and calculating for that values my final loan(that is `ratanks` part). Now I'm also extracting some other data that I need present to the user on the frontend.

Now my problem: It's sending my `res` as an object with one object, who has key:value pairs and values are array of data inside it. But I want it to be an array with multiple objects.

My response in postman right now:

```
{
    "kredit": {
        "kreditNKS": [
            118406.54,
            118348.2,
            119400.33,
            118022.46,
            118262.44,
            118811.84
        ],
        "rataNKS": [
            19734.42,
            19724.7,
            19900.05,
            19670.41,
            19710.41,
            19801.97
        ],
        "stopaEKS": [
            "6.24",
            "5.65",
            "8.26",
            "3.13",
            "4.03",
            "5.68"
        ],
        "stopaNKS": [
            "4.11",
            "3.94",
            "7",
            "2.99",
            "3.69",
            "5.29"
        ],
        "tip": [
            "Fiksna",
            "Promjenjiva",
            "Fiksna",
            "Promjenjiva",
            "Fiksna",
            "Fiksna"
        ],
        "ime": [
            "ZiraatBank",
            "ZiraatBank",
            "UniCredit",
            "Raiffeisen Bank",
            "Raiffeisen Bank",
            "ASA Banka"
        ]
    }
}
```

Where I need it to be something like this:

```
[
   {
      "kreditNKS":118406.54,
      "rataNKS": 19734.42,
      "stopaEKS": "6.24",
      "stopaNKS": "4.11",
      "tip": "Fiksna",
      "ime": "ZiraatBank"
   },
   {
      "kreditNKS":118348.2,
      "rataNKS": 19724.7,
      "stopaEKS": "5.65",
      "stopaNKS": "3.94",
      "tip": "Promjenjiva",
      "ime": "ZiraatBank"
   },
   {
      "kreditNKS":119400.33,
      "rataNKS": 19900,05,
      "stopaEKS": "8.26",
      "stopaNKS": "7",
      "tip": "Fiksna",
      "ime": "UniCredit"
   }
   etc.....
]
```

Is it possible to modify something like this?

Any tips are welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you're mapping your list into 4 arrays and then putting them inside a single object, where each array is a property of the said object.

```js
let eks = list.map((stopa) => stopa.EKS);
let name = list.map((ime) => ime.bank.name);
let nks = list.map((stopa) => stopa.NKS);
let type = list.map((ime) => ime.interest_type.name);

res.status(200).json({
  kredit: {
    kreditNKS: kreditNKS,
    rataNKS: rataNKS,
    stopaEKS: eks,
    stopaNKS: nks,
    tip: type,
    ime: name,
  }
})
```

The way `someArray.map(eachThing => doSomethingWithThing(thing))` works is that you iterate the entire array "someArray" and execute a function for each thing inside of it.

This means that instead of doing `LoanJS.Loan(price, !mjeseci ? 60 : mjeseci, rata.NKS)` for all the items of the list and write that to a new array called "ratanks", you can write your own function for all the items of the list, and during the iteration of each item do something like `const loan = LoanJS.Loan(price, !mjeseci ? 60 : mjeseci, eachItem.NKS)`.

This being said, you should be able to get the object you want by mapping your list into an array of objects like this

```js
const mappedKredits = list.map((eachObject) => {
  const computedLoan = LoanJS.Loan(price, !mjeseci ? 60 : mjeseci, eachObject.NKS);
  const kreditNKS = computedLoan.sum;
  const rataNKS = computedLoan.installments[0].installment;
  return {
    "kreditNKS": kreditNKS,
    "rataNKS": rataNKS,
    "stopaEKS": eachObject.EKS,
    "stopaNKS": eachObject.NKS,
    "tip": eachObject.interest_type.name,
    "ime": eachObject.bank.name,
  }
});

res.status(200).json(mappedKredits);
```

Btw, try to use more descriptive names for the variables, if they're in English it'll be even better, otherwise, it makes it a bit harder for folks like me to understand what the code is doing, thus making it harder to help you.